# how can I resolve a collision between two events, click outside and on the button to close a menu in svelte kit?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, svelte, sveltekit

I have a problem in `svelteKit` with a collision. The button opens the menu but when I try to close it, it doesn't. When I click outside the button, this triggers `handleClickOutside` which calls `clickOutside.js`, and then closes the menu.

I think that the problem is that `element.contains` includes the button and for that, the menu didn't close.

however, I couldn't fix it.

I'm using `tailwindUI`, `tailwindCSS`, `SvelteKit`.

***index.svelte***

```
<script>
    // @ts-nocheck
    import bostonLogo from '../../img/bostonLogo.png';
    import { clickOutside } from '../../lib/clickOutside';

    // Example Profile
    let profile = {
        name: 'Matias',
        lastName: 'Barletta'
    };

    // Show/Hide Menu

    let menu = false;

    // COLLISION WITH HANDLENAV
    
    function handleClickOutside(event) {            
        menu = false;   
    }

    function handleNav() {

        menu = !menu;
        
    }

</script>

<div>
    <!-- Static sidebar for desktop -->
    <div class=" md:flex md:w-64 md:flex-col md:fixed md:inset-y-0" class:hidden={!menu}>
        <!-- Sidebar component, swap this element with another sidebar if you like -->
        <div
            use:clickOutside
            on:click_outside={menu? handleClickOutside : ''}
            class:absolute={menu}
            class:mt-11={menu}
            class="md:flex-1 md:flex md:flex-col md:min-h-0 bg-gray-800"
        >
...
```

***clickOutside.js***

```
// @ts-nocheck
/** Dispatch event on click outside of element */
// @ts-ignore

export function clickOutside(element) {
    // @ts-ignore

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target, document.body)
    
        // element exist?, element contain where i did click, preventDefault = false?
        if (element && !element.contains(event.target) && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            element.dispatchEvent(
                // Dispatch and create new custom event.
                new CustomEvent('click_outside', element)
            );
        }
    };
    // add eventlistener when you click on document
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);

    return {
        destroy() {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick, true);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this exact same issue not too long ago. My solution was to just ignore the menu click when the menu is open. You already have this: `on:click_outside={menu? handleClickOutside : ''}`.

So now if the menu is closed, the action won't fire. If the menu is open, the menu button won't fire. So there's always just 1 callback that's being called.

```
function handleNav() {
    if (menu) return;
    menu = !menu;
}
```

---

As an Alternative you could add options to the action so that the `handleClick` function can ignore the click if the target is within a list of ignored selectors (rather than just the element it is on).

### Update

The alternative approach here, with a [working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/cf41fb920f90453990aeff95a88e4e3b?version=3.55.1) (updated 13/01/2023).

What we do, is we added an ID to the menu button

```html
<button
  id="menu-button"
  type="button"
  value="button"
  class="-ml-0.5 -mt-0.5 h-12 w-12 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500"
  on:click={handleNav}
  >...</button>
```

We then add that ID as a parameter to the `use:clickOutside` action:

```html
<div
  use:clickOutside={{ignore: 'menu-button'}}
  on:click_outside={menu? handleClickOutside : ''}
  class:absolute={menu}
  class:mt-11={menu}
  class="md:flex-1 md:flex md:flex-col md:min-h-0 bg-gray-800"
  >
  <div class="h-40 w-40 bg-slate-600 p-3 text-white">
    Some menu content here
  </div>
</div>
```

And then in the action, we get the element by ID and check if we're in it.

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // This function kinda rearranged with early returns to take the new parameter into account.
  if (!element) return;
  if (element.contains(event.target)) return;
  
  //Get the element based on the id we gave in the params
  const ignore = document.getElementById(opts.ignore)
  //Check that we're not clicking in the button.
  if (ignore.contains(event.target)) return;
  
  element.dispatchEvent(
    // Dispatch and create new custom event.
    new CustomEvent('click_outside', element)
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I've already tried adding options by putting a conditional in clickOutside.js that compares to the event.target,is that what you mean?. The problem is that it always, the event.target, takes the element in which the action is implemented. In this case, always takes the 'div button menu'. So i can't take  button like a exception.

Comment: If you could create your scenario with a repl, I can see if I can show you how to fix it (https://svelte.dev/repl)

Comment: I created this REPL. You have to look at mobile version. Thanks!

https://svelte.dev/repl/3c1e7112967743039850de7081a8ee20?version=3.48.0

Comment: I've updated the original answer. As a friendly suggestion, in the future please minimize your REPL to only the necessary stuff. It's generally easier for strangers to help you if they don't have to sort through a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: @Coo, your Repl is returning a 404. Would it be possible for you to see what going on, please? Would love to see your implementation there 

Comment: @ItzaMi REPL has been remade. Not sure what happened to the old one, but this one should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Typescript Version with Tailwind**

Anybody coming in the future. Here is the typescript version.

**click_outside.ts**

```
export function clickOutside(node: HTMLElement, opts?: string) {
    function detect({ target }: MouseEvent) {
        if (opts !== undefined) {
            const ignore = document.getElementById(opts);
            if (ignore?.contains(target as Node)) return;

            if (!node.contains(target as Node)) {
                node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('clickoutside'));
            }
        } else {
            if (!node.contains(target as Node)) {
                node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('clickoutside'));
            }
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', detect, { passive: true, capture: true });
    return {
        destroy() {
            document.removeEventListener('click', detect);
        }
    };
}
```

**app.d.ts (for adding types)**

```
declare namespace svelteHTML {
        interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
            'on:clickoutside'?: (event: CustomEvent) => void;
        }
    }
```

**+page.svelte**

```
<svelte:head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</svelte:head>

<script>
    import { clickOutside } from './click_outside';

    let menu = false;
</script>

<button
  id="menu-button"
  type="button"
  value="button"
  class="p-2"
  on:click={()=> {menu = !menu}}
  >Click!</button>

<div
  use:clickOutside={'menu-button'}
  on:click_outside={()=> {menu = false}}
  
  class={`${menu ? 'block' : 'hidden'} absolute bg-blue-500 top-16 left-0 bg-slate-100 p-2`}  
  >
  <div>
    Some menu content here
  </div>
</div>
```